# Redis lindex works but not lpop

Tags: redis, jedis

I'm seeing this strange behavior. I do a `lpush` to a key. There is a different service that listens to key notifications and tries to `lpop` the value. But strangely it returns null. If I do a `lindex` with 0 as index, I get the value. So, I know for sure the value is available. I can see that using `redis-cli`. But `lpop` does not return the value.

I use redis 2.8.13 and Jedis Java framework. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

To debug this try to use redis [MONITOR](http://redis.io/commands/monitor) command (for example by running `redis-cli monitor` in a shell on the redis host) to see:

- what commands are really being sent to your redis,
- when
- and by which client.

It is a long shot without seeing the code but I think that your code using Jedis is not sending exactly the commands you think it is sending.